# Excel suming a vlookup array that is based off other values to define the size of the array

Tags: arrays, excel, sum

trying to do a formula only calculator and trying to avoid a bunch of nested ifs in "hidden" columns.

Basically this is a calculator for COC type of game.

So here is a rough table (not sure how to best make a table here):

```
      A              B                 K            M
1   name      current level      Max Level   Next level cost
6   Soldier        2                  4              X
```

where x=IF($K6=B6,0,VLOOKUP($A6,Masterdata!$A$4:$CD$50,32+B6,0)))

the masterdata sheet is just the name some data across several columns, some more data across several columns, and then individual columns that contain a cost starting on column 32.

this works to find the cost of the next level (3) but I would like to do a `sum` with something like:  `IF($K6=B6,0,sum(VLOOKUP($A6,Masterdata!$A$4:$CD$50,{32+B6, 33+B6,34+b6},0))))`. I can get the array to work if I put in fixed numbers ie, `{35, 36, 37}` but not `{32+B6, 33+B6,34+b6}`. Additionally, the array won't dynamically change. such as `current level=1, max level=9` will require a larger array than `current level =5 max, max level=9`. Is there a way of doing this?

Further explanation of 2nd part:
example:
current level =1 max level =9
the formula would be something like: `IF($K6=B6,0,sum(VLOOKUP($A6,Masterdata!$A$4:$CD$50,{32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39},0))))` I would require 8 columns in the array to be added.

But if current level is 6 and max level is 9 then it would look something like this:`IF($K6=B6,0,sum(VLOOKUP($A6,Masterdata!$A$4:$CD$50,{37,38,39},0))))`
I would only require 3 columns returned in the array to be added.

So even if the formula needs to remain `IF($K6=B6,0,sum(VLOOKUP($A6,Masterdata!$A$4:$CD$50,{32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39},0))))` I would like to constrain the results to only columns 37,38,39

Comment: What is the relationship between current level, max level, and the array of values which are to be used for the column_index_num parameter? If current level = 1, for example, is the first value in that array 32? And if current level = 5 it's 36? What about max level?

Comment: @XORLX yes 1 would be 32 (column 32 of the lookup) 2 would equate to 33 column lookup.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I abandoned the `vlookup` and went the `index match` route:
Came up with: `=SUM(INDEX(Masterdata!$A$1:$Z$32,MATCH($A26,Masterdata!$A$1:$A$32,0),B26+1+14):INDEX(Masterdata!$A$1:$Z$32,MATCH($A26,Masterdata!$A$1:$A$32,0),E26+14))`

Seems to work great.

Basically I am finding the row number that matches my search criteria:`MATCH($A26,Masterdata!$A$1:$A$32,0)` = 26

I then enter that into an index with an offset of my first column based off my min value:`index(range,26,B26+1+14)`, along with the max value:`index(range,26,E26+14)` and then sum them together `sum(index1:index2)`

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude the cell reference from the array of constants. And you will require `SUMPRODUCT` (or else `SUM` with `CSE`) to coerce an array of returns:

`=IF($K6=B6,0,SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP($A6,Masterdata!$A$4:$CD$50,{32,33,34}+B6,0)))`

I'm afraid I don't understand your second query re "the array won't dynamically change".

Regards

Comment: so cell reference cannot be included in the array of constants?  As far as the second part.  I will elaborate in question

Comment: No, but why is it a problem to construct the array as I have?

Comment: See comment under the main question